# Replace needle in haystack

Tags: jquery

Only my haystack is an *attribute value* not an element. Consider the following DOM snip:

```
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link1</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link2</a>
```

I want to loop through the entire document looking for references to `google.com`  replacing these with `another.com` say. I should be able to run this in the console with the paths updated and visible immediately.

Here's my stab at it:

```
jQuery(document).find("a").each(function(i,j){
 $_this = jQuery(this).attr('href');
 $_this.replace('http://google.com', 'https://another.com');
 //console.log($_this);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've successfully replaced the value.  You just forgot to assign the result of it to anything...

```
$_this = jQuery(this).attr('href');
$_that = $_this.replace('http://google.com', 'https://another.com');
jQuery(this).attr('href', $_that);
```

Answer (score 2):

Select only the `<a>` tags which `href=` starts with `http://google.com/` and then no need to assign values to variables.

```js
$('a[href^="http://google.com/"]').each(function(element){
    $(this).attr(
        'href', 
        $(this).attr('href').replace(
            'http://google.com',
            'https://another.com'
        )
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link1</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link2</a>
```

and the same in plain javascript would look like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http://google.com/"]').forEach(
    function(element){
        element.href = element.href.replace(
            'http://google.com',
            'https://another.com'
        );
    }
);
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link1</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

so selecting every element is a little overkill, how about simply selecting the ones you wish to change? And then, go ahead and change them?

```js
// get only those elements point at google
$("[href*='google.com']").each(function() {
  // change their url string via regex
  var myUrl = $(this).attr("href")
    .replace(/http:\/\/google.com/gi, "https://foo.org")
  // update the url on the el, and show it.
  //  just so you see SOMETHING happened.
  $(this).attr("href", myUrl)
    .text("my link is now " + myUrl);
})
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link1</a>
<a href="http://google.com/path/to/file/file.png">link2</a>
```